# Hibernate FetchMode.JOIN with one to many mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are two entity InvoiceHeader and InvoiceDetail with one to many mapping as below.

**InvoiceHeader**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_invoice_hdr")
@IdClass(InvoiceHdrPK.class)
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class InvoiceHeader{
  
  ....
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceHeader", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
  private List<InvoiceDetail> items;
}
```

**InvoiceHdrPK**

```
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class InvoiceHdrPK implements Serializable {

    private String invoiceNumber;
    private InvoiceSource invoiceSource;
    private InvoiceType invoiceType;
    private Long companyId;
    private Integer invoiceYear;
}
```

Similarly **InvoiceDetail**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_inv_dtl")
@IdClass(InvoiceDetailPK.class)
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class InvoiceDetail{
  
  ....
  
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_number", referencedColumnName = "invoice_number", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_source", referencedColumnName = "invoice_source", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_type", referencedColumnName = "invoice_type", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_year", referencedColumnName = "invoice_year", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    })
    private InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader;
}
```

**InvoiceDetailPK**

```
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class InvoiceDetailPK implements Serializable {

    private String invoiceNumber;
    private InvoiceSource invoiceSource;
    private InvoiceType invoiceType;
    private BigDecimal rate;
    private Long itemNo;
    private Long companyId;
    private Integer invoiceYear;

}
```

Both the entities are not an actual table in db level but are maintained as views.

**Using JPA** I am trying to fetch invoices using **findAll(Specification, pageable)** with **FetchMode.JOIN** to avoid **n+1** query problem.

But getting exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list...
```

So how can I fix this and what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use Set instead of List @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceHeader", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set items = new HashSet<>();

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use a query similar to this `select b from A a join a.b b join fetch a.c`. The gist is, you join fetch some association that you never refer to through the parent in the select clause.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have found the issue and it was with ```findAll(specification, pageable)```. The issue was with pagination provided.As we use pagination Spring Data JPA executes two queries; one to get the number of rows matching the query, and one that fetches the data for a given page.The problem here is when paging, it will call a count query, but the count query doesn't allow fetch. Fixed this by preventing fetch in count query

Comment: If you want more efficient pagination while still using the Spring Data API, take a look at the Spring Data integration of Blaze-Persistence: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-integration